# Brake pedal to the floor

Tags: ford, brakes, falcon

1962 Ford Falcon. I adjusted the brakes (drums all round, with power booster) and now i frequently get the brake pedal going almost to the floor before working. Master cylinder or wheel cylinders need a kit, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no leaks, then I would first suspect that the shoes are not adjusted close enough to the drums.

This then means all the pistons have to move too much which demands more volume of fluid and then the pedal has to travel further.

So, re-check the brake shoe adjustment.

Comment: I agree. If, however, the pedal still feels soft when the brakes begin to work, I'd suspect the master cylinder is failing.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Translation of text from Google Translate -

You should have the brake booster checked and/or maintained. What you are commenting on is an indication of this failure. I hope my comment is useful to you.

Debes de mandar a revisar y/o mantenimiento del bosster de los frenos.Lo que comentas es un indicativo de esta falla.Espero y te sirva mi comentario

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please realize, this Stack is an English speaking only site. We appreciate you being here and answering, but we need you to post your questions and answers in English.